# Elm Graphics.Input

Tags: elm

I'm trying to run the Elm input examples from [this page](http://elm-lang.org/examples/Basic.elm). Specifically, the [Text Field](http://elm-lang.org/edit/examples/Reactive/TextField.elm) example, and I'm getting an error saying that the `Graphics.Input` module is missing.

I've got this in a file called `Main.elm`:

```
import Graphics.Input as Input

main = let (field, state) = Input.field "Type here!"
       in  lift2 display field state

display field state =
  field `above` asText state
```

If I run `elm-server` and navigate to `localhost:8000`, I get the error

```
Your browser may not be supported. Are you using a modern browser?

Runtime Error in Main module:
Error: Module 'Graphics.Input' is missing. Compile with --make flag or load missing module in a separate JavaScript file.

The problem may stem from an improper usage of:
Input.field, above
```

Compiling the project with `elm --make Main.elm` gives me

```
elm: Graphics/Input.elm: openFile: does not exist (No such file or directory)
```

Is there something extra I need to do to install the `Graphic.Input`?

**Additional Notes:**

- I'm running this on a Debian machine, and installed it using `cabal install elm` fairly recently (Jun 15 2013). The current version is labeled `Elm-0.7.1.1`.
- If I hop into the `chromium` JS prompt and poke around, it turns out there's no `Elm.Graphics.Input` module, but there *is* an `Elm.Input`. There isn't a function called `field`, there's a similar looking one called `textField`, but it isn't trivially interchangeable.

Running this:

```
import Input

main = let (field, state) = textField "Type here!"
       in  lift2 display field state

display field state =
  field `above` asText state
```

gives me the error

```
Your browser may not be supported. Are you using a modern browser?

Runtime Error in Main module:
TypeError: a is undefined

The problem may stem from an improper usage of:
above
```

Comment: When did you install elm? Just now or was it some time ago? Which version do you have installed?

Comment: A couple of days ago. The folder in `.cabal/share` is called `Elm-0.7.1.1`, so I assume that's the version I've got. Updated the question with additional notes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `Graphics.Input` package is new in [version 0.8](http://elm-lang.org/blog/announce/version-0.8.elm#dynamic-inputs). So, since you're running version 0.7, that explains your problem.

0.8 was released somewhat recently, but it's definitely been out longer than June 15th, so you probably just forgot to `cabal update` before installing it. Running `cabal update` now and then updating elm to 0.8 should fix your issue.